# xSocket ExtendedClosedChannelException

Tags: java, sockets

I have an error that I sometimes met. The error stack trace is below;

```
   2011-05-04-xWorkerPool-1-thread-2--FATAL-su.games.engine.communication.gameSocketDataHandler:ServiceSocketDataHandler.onData:
could not write. channel is close or not initialized (id=25c1031512fb560155a71db6548S1517c (closed))-----
org.xsocket.connection.ExtendedClosedChannelException: could not write. channel is close or not initialized (id=25c1031512fb560155a71db6548S1517c (closed))
at org.xsocket.connection.AbstractNonBlockingStream.ensureStreamIsOpenAndWritable(AbstractNonBlockingStream.java:1537)
at org.xsocket.connection.AbstractNonBlockingStream.write(AbstractNonBlockingStream.java:1054)
at org.xsocket.connection.AbstractNonBlockingStream.write(AbstractNonBlockingStream.java:1039)
at su.games.engine.communication.ServiceSocketDataHandler.onData(ServiceSocketDataHandler.java:63)
at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter.performOnData(HandlerAdapter.java:242)
at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter.access$200(HandlerAdapter.java:42)
at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter$PerformOnDataTask.run(HandlerAdapter.java:210)
at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue.performPendingTasks(SerializedTaskQueue.java:161)
at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue.access$100(SerializedTaskQueue.java:40)
at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue$MultithreadedTaskProcessor.run(SerializedTaskQueue.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I use the xSocket 2.8.15 version(jar). Sorry for the tag I have permission issue to create a new tag.The error can be defined as follows. I have number of INonBlockingConnection object and when I try to write some data by using the nbc.write() I get an error as defined above. I search the google and visit the xSocket mailing list. But I can not find any solution. I need some help. Thanks the site StackOverflow and help sorry for the English. I am waiting your advice.

KingSpeech.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears fairly self explanatory. It appears that your connection has been closed or failed to connect.  This is most likely due to a problem on the other side (or your network)